# Como remover elementos duplicados numa matriz multidimensional

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

Alguém poderia me ajudar por gentileza, como faço para remover os elementos do array duplicados levado em conta a chave "Nome", porem retornando dos Nomes duplicados o que tem a maior data

```
<?

// MEU ARRAY 
$array =  [
  0 => array:4 [
    "Nome" => "Bruno"
    "Modalidade" => "AA , JJ , HHHH"
    "Valor" => "30.00"
    "Data Pagamento" => "2020-07-04"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "Nome" => "Alice Costa"
    "Modalidade" => "AA , JJ , HHHH"
    "Valor" => "600.00"
    "Data Pagamento" => "2020-08-04"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "Nome" => "Alice Costa"
    "Modalidade" => "AA , JJ , HHHH"
    "Valor" => "600.00"
    "Data Pagamento" => "2020-09-04"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [
    "Nome" => "Jamir"
    "Modalidade" => "AA , TESTE"
    "Valor" => "50.00"
    "Data Pagamento" => "2020-06-04"
  ]
  4 => array:4 [
    "Nome" => "Jamir"
    "Modalidade" => "AA , TESTE"
    "Valor" => "200.00"
    "Data Pagamento" => "2020-10-04"
  ]
];

// RESULTADO ESPERADO

$array =  [
  0 => array:4 [
    "Nome" => "Bruno"
    "Modalidade" => "AA , JJ , HHHH"
    "Valor" => "30.00"
    "Data Pagamento" => "2020-07-04"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "Nome" => "Alice Costa"
    "Modalidade" => "AA , JJ , HHHH"
    "Valor" => "600.00"
    "Data Pagamento" => "2020-09-04"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "Nome" => "Jamir"
    "Modalidade" => "AA , TESTE"
    "Valor" => "200.00"
    "Data Pagamento" => "2020-10-04"
  ]
];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode transformar seu *array* em uma *Collection* e usar os métodos `groupBy` e `map`

```
$users = collect($array)->groupBy('Nome')->map(static function($users) {
    return $users->last();
});
```

É possível também fazer uma filtragem na consulta, mas pra isso precisaria primeiro saber como está sendo feita a consulta.

Comment: boa tarde Erlon, infelizmente não deu, converti em coleção porem ainda continua pegando os que tem a menor data de pagamento, a ideia era trazer os que tem a data mais recentes

Comment: Nesse caso, ainda com collections vc pode usar ``groupBy('name')` e em seguida usar o `map()` pra pegar a penas o último, mas o melhor mesmo é saber como essa consulta está sendo feita, sempre é mais rápido usar o banco e fazer uma consulta bem específica

Comment: infelizmente essa tratativa vou ter que realizar no código, apesar de no banco realmente ser mais rápido, por que na situação que tenho que realizar não vou poder fazer pelo banco, mas você pode elaborar um exemplo por gentileza de como ficaria usando o map ?